# Send Emails to more than one person using Power Shell 1.0

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send E-Mails to more than one receipient using OG Powershell 1.0 . However I am failing. I guess I misunderstood the `foreach` loop, but I am not sure. Can someone help me out?

```
[string[]]$receipients = "my@mail.com", "mysecond@mail.com"

foreach ($person in $receipients){
    $mail = @{
        SmtpServer = 'mycoolserver.com'
        Port = 33
        From = "me"
        To = "$person"
        Subject = "mycoolsubject"
        Body = "Hey guys!"
    }
    Send-MailMessage @mail 
    Write-Host "$person received"
}
```

It also only logs my@mail.com mysecond@mail.com received. (That's why I think the loop is wrong defined.)

Comment: You misspelled recipients in your foreach.

Comment: @notjustme I only messed up the capitals, didn't I? That does not matter as far as I am concerned. Changing it also did not help.

Comment: I see no capitals in those variable names. Compare  $recipients and $receipients. Clearly different spelling.

Comment: This has to be said: upgrade powershell. At least to PS 2 which even works on XP/2003

Comment: The Port parameter of Send-Mailmessage is only available in PowerShell 3.0 and newer.
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage#-port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using PS v1, you cannot use the -Port parameter.
If you are happy to use the default port 25, then the following code should work for you (including suggestion of James C):

```
[string[]]$recipients = "my@mail.com", "mysecond@mail.com"
foreach ($person in $recipients)
{
    Send-MailMessage `
        -SmtpServer "mycoolserver.com" `
        -From "me@domain.com" `
        -To "$person" `
        -Subject "mycoolsubject" `
        -Body "Hey guys!"
    Write-Host "$person received"
}
```

If you must use another port, like the port 33 in your question, then try this version:

```
[string[]]$recipients = "my@mail.com", "mysecond@mail.com"
foreach ($person in $recipients)
{
    $mailfrom = "me@domain.com"
    $mailto = $person
    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($mailfrom, $mailto)
    $mail.Subject = "mycoolsubject"
    $mail.Body = "Hey guys!"
    $mailserver = "mycoolserver.com"
    $mailclient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    $mailclient.Host = $mailserver
    $mailclient.Port = 33
    $mailclient.send($mail)
    Write-Host "$person received"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Parameter Splatting which was a new feature of PowerShell v2, which does not work with PS v1.

You'll need to just assign the parameters directly like this:

```
[string[]]$recipients = "my@mail.com", "mysecond@mail.com"

foreach ($person in $recipients)
{
    Send-MailMessage `
        -SmtpServer 'mycoolserver.com' `
        -Port 33 `
        -From "me" `
        -To "$person" `
        -Subject "mycoolsubject" `
        -Body "Hey guys!" `
    Write-Host "$person received" `
}
```

Comment: Testing this in PowerShell v1 shows that it does not work as the -Port param is not available. Also I would think that the backticks on lines 11 & 12 (-body & Write-Host) should be removed.